# Problem with ntfs-3g in Linux Mint 20 (Ulyana)?

Tags: linux-mint, ntfs-3g, lsusb

I really need to ask this as this has been very frustrating for me for the *entire week*.

I have a 2 TB external hard drive (Transcend 25H3) that I'm using to back up my data in Linux Mint 20 (Ulyana). I've noticed that the file transfer is so staggeringly slow (max. ~1 MB/s) which I first attributed to the external drive's performance. I've NTFS reformatted the disk so many times, but the performance was still the same. In addition, the disk takes forever (stuck with a spinning circle) to unmount/shut down through the `Disks Utility` in Mint. While this is happening, I tried to shut down the computer, but I'm redirected to the lock screen. So, I just unplug the cable, thus corrupting files which I fix using `chkdsk` in Windows 10.

However, when I plugged another external drive (1 TB Seagate Backup Slim), I noticed the same problems with performance and unpluggability (if that word exists).

Using `umount` (even `umount -f`) also takes forever to complete. I took a look at `mount` and confirmed that the drive is no longer mounted, but `ps aux` shows that `mount.ntfs` mounting the drive is indeed still there in a `Ds` status.

When I used the Transcend drive in Windows to test read and write, I was getting fast transfer speeds (~30 MB/s), and unmounting/safe removal is a breeze.

With all that said, could this be a possible problem with `ntfs-3g`? Or, is it a problem with the Linux Mint disk/partition itself? I'm running a dual-booted Windows (NTFS) and Linux Mint (ext4) system.

**Update 1:**

Used `lsusb -s <bus>:<serial> -v` to check the status of my USB 3.1 port and this is what I got:

```
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               3.10
      bDeviceClass            9 Hub
      bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bDeviceProtocol         3 
      bMaxPacketSize0         9
      idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
      idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
      bcdDevice            5.04
      iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.4.0-77-generic xhci-hcd
      iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
      iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength       0x001f
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0xe0
          Self Powered
          Remote Wakeup
        MaxPower                0mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           1
          bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
          iInterface              0 
          Endpoint Descriptor:
            bLength                 7
            bDescriptorType         5
            bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
            bmAttributes            3
              Transfer Type            Interrupt
              Synch Type               None
              Usage Type               Data
            wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
            bInterval              12
            bMaxBurst               0
    Hub Descriptor:
      bLength              12
      bDescriptorType      42
      nNbrPorts             6
      wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
        No power switching (usb 1.0)
        Per-port overcurrent protection
      bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
      bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
      bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
      wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
      DeviceRemovable    0x00
     Hub Port Status:
       Port 1: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
       Port 2: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
       Port 3: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
       Port 4: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
       Port 5: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
       Port 6: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
    Binary Object Store Descriptor:
      bLength                 5
      bDescriptorType        15
      wTotalLength       0x005b
      bNumDeviceCaps          2
      SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        16
        bDevCapabilityType      3
        bmAttributes         0x02
          Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
        wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
          Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
        bFunctionalitySupport   3
          Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
        bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
        bU2DevExitLat         918 micro seconds
      SuperSpeedPlus USB Device Capability:
        bLength                76
        bDescriptorType        16
        bDevCapabilityType     10
        bmAttributes         0x000000ef
          Sublink Speed Attribute count 15
          Sublink Speed ID count 7
        wFunctionalitySupport   0x0001
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[0]   0x00050034
          Speed Attribute ID: 4 5Gb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[1]   0x000500b4
          Speed Attribute ID: 4 5Gb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[2]   0x000a4035
          Speed Attribute ID: 5 10Gb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeedPlus
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[3]   0x000a40b5
          Speed Attribute ID: 5 10Gb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeedPlus
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[4]   0x04e00026
          Speed Attribute ID: 6 1248Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[5]   0x04e000a6
          Speed Attribute ID: 6 1248Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[6]   0x09c00027
          Speed Attribute ID: 7 2496Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[7]   0x09c000a7
          Speed Attribute ID: 7 2496Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[8]   0x13800028
          Speed Attribute ID: 8 4992Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[9]   0x138000a8
          Speed Attribute ID: 8 4992Mb/s Symmcan't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
    etric TX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[10]   0x05b10029
          Speed Attribute ID: 9 1457Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[11]   0x05b100a9
          Speed Attribute ID: 9 1457Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[12]   0x0b63002a
          Speed Attribute ID: 10 2915Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[13]   0x0b6300aa
          Speed Attribute ID: 10 2915Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[14]   0x16c6002b
          Speed Attribute ID: 11 5830Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
        bmSublinkSpeedAttr[15]   0x16c600ab
          Speed Attribute ID: 11 5830Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
    Device Status:     0x0001
      Self Powered
```

It says that `Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)`, but what concerns me is that it says `Hub Port Status: Port [1-6]: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1`. Could this be the limiting factor as to why read and write speeds on USB is so slow? I've tried using the live boot of Linux Mint and Arch Linux, but both also shows the same hub port status.

**Update 2:**

Here's the output of `lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Comment: I've got at least five NTFS partitions and they all work just fine under `ntfs-3g` (the performance for operations on small files is quite low but that's a FUSE limitation). Try formatting your drive as e.g. `ext4` and make sure it works OK. Maybe it's not about `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Please check the info from ```lsusb``` that I've updated into my post.

Comment: Please post the output of `lsusb -t`. Even for USB2 your read/write speeds must be at the very least 30MB/sec not 1MB/sec - that's USB 1.1 speeds (12Mbit/sec).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've added the output of ```lsusb -t```. I've been reading around and saw that this problem is existent in many Linux distros. I suspect that this could be a problem with Linux configuration itself?

Comment: I don't see your external disk drive in the output. Is it connected now? I've been using external disk drives via USB in Linux for over a decade now and I've had zero issues with performance. They work either as fast as they can be when the interface is faster, or as fast as the interface allows when the interface is slower.